# C# OracleDataAdapater fill command throws "index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, dataset, oracle12c, indexoutofboundsexception

I am running into this issue and not sure how to resolve it or how to get more info on the error so I can pinpoint the source.

I am executing an Oracle query that uses data adapter to fill a dataset. It throws an index outside the bounds of an array and I can't even see what array is being referred to!

I run the query inside SQL Developer and runs fine and returns the results, so I am pretty sure it is not the query itself.

```
public DataSet GetItemsByDateRange(string[] saLabelIDs, DateTime dtStartDate, DateTime dtEndDate)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    List<OracleParameter> spParams = new List<OracleParameter>();
    string sLabelIDs = "'" + String.Join("','", saLabelIDs) + "'";

    string sQuery = "SELECT /*+ FULL(t) PARALLEL(t, 32)*/ * " +
        "FROM SomeTable@DBLinkName t " +
        "WHERE (R_LAST_UPDT_DT >= :StartDate AND R_LAST_UPDT_DT <= :EndDate) " +
        "AND R_ID IN(" + sLabelIDs + ") " +
        "ORDER BY R_ID, R_ITEM_LABEL, R_LAST_UPDT_DT DESC";

    try
    {
        spParams.Add(new OracleParameter("StartDate", OracleDbType.Timestamp, dtStartDate, ParameterDirection.Input));
        spParams.Add(new OracleParameter("EndDate", OracleDbType.Timestamp, dtEndDate, ParameterDirection.Input));
        dbContext.Open();
        dbContext.ExecuteOraAdapterFillCmd(sQuery, spParams, ref ds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        dbContext.Close();
    }
    return ds;
}

public void ExecuteOraAdapterFillCmd(string sQuery, List<OracleParameter> spParams, ref DataSet dataset)
{
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddRange(spParams.ToArray<OracleParameter>());
        command.Connection = DbConnection;
        command.CommandText = sQuery;
        command.BindByName = true;

        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
        try
        {
            da.Fill(dataset);
        }
        catch(OracleException oex)
        {

        }
        catch(Exception ex) // Throws error here 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It probably doesn't solve your problem, but you should be able to pass in the parameter values as DateTime values and not do all of the date formatting and parsing.

Comment: @DStanley updated question, still same error; no clue whatsoever what array is being referred to here!

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the parameters, but I can't see anything wrong just by looking at the code. Have you run it in the debugger? Are the parameters getting added to the command properly?

Comment: @DStanley Yes, I have been debugging this all day, I actually removed everything except for "select * from ..." removed the WHERE and ORDER clauses and parameters, still getting the same error. No hair left to pull!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an Oracle data access issue. Apparently it uses an array internally when dealing with DB links and my DB link looked like tbl_name@someName.x.y; I am not sure but maybe splits it by dot and expects 2 elements and gets 3.

To test this I used:

```
create synonym tbl_name for tbl_name@someName.x.y;
```

I replaced the DB link in my query with 'tbl_name' and it worked.